# NSPredicate bug when string contains ' in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I'm setting the string of my predicate like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(name like '%@')",name]
```

but if name contains `'` characters, for example if name is `"family's"` it crashes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to accept it, thank you so much - it has been of a great help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the ' in `NSPredicate`. They are being inserted automatically.

Just try

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name like %@)",name];
```

---

The reason this crashed was because the predicate value was interrupted.
If you create a string with format, like in your example, your going to end up with **(name like 'family's')**, which obviously can't work.

If you use `predicateWithFormat:` on the other hand, you can let it handle this itself. It will escape your special characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want/aren't able to use `predicateWithFormat`, then you can simply replace any apostrophes in your string.

I do this in my app, when checking my `UISearchBar` control, to see if the user's trying to look for particular CoreData records:

```
NSString* searchString = self.searchBar.text;
if (searchString.length != 0)
{
    searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
    NSString* filter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"companyName CONTAINS[cd] '%@'", searchString];

    NSPredicate* predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filter]; 

    //  ...etc... 
}
```

(This is a simplified version of a generic function I use, which actually searches CoreData using a variable number of filter strings, which is why I don't use `predicateWithFormat` directly.)